# How to define a custom private ethernetType in pcap.net

Tags: c#, pcap.net

pcap.net support some public `ethernetType` in its `enum EthernetType`

There are serval ether type values listed above dedicated for IPV4,IPV6 and ARP protocol types.
For IPV4, ether type = `0x0800`.
But how to define a custome private etherType(for example `0x8899`)?

Answer (score 0):

Following [a discussion in Pcap.Net Q&A Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pcapdotnet/XzaB_nCTcSc),
I have tried to cast `ushort` value into `EthernetType`, and it works.